# Print image from image object in the middle of HTML without saving

Tags: php, image

I use the imagic extension. I have an `$image_obj` object. I can just echo it but it makes it look like random number of characters unless I put:

```
$Obj_img->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image_obj;
```

Is there way to actually put it like this:

```
echo "<html>
<body>
this is my image: {$image_obj}
</body>
</html>";
```

I know you can do

```
echo "this is my image <img src="raw:{$image_obj}" />
```

but is there any other way without saving document to a file?

Comment: Careful doing it this way, you will be using more resources than saving the files once and having the users request the files. If your script get slow or you start having memory errors this will be a good place to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an `image.php` script that generates the image, and point to it inside your html:

```
<img src="image.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&..."/>
```

Comment: going to need more details please on whats inside image.php and
why so many params?

Comment: `image.php` holds the code you posted in your question. Params are just in case you need to generate the image based on some `$_GET` parameter of course.

Comment: Works, thanks your genious. however, is there way to protect somehow against saving image right now they can just do save as and it saves image.php.png

Comment: No - think they can take a screenshot of the page ^^

Comment: If we were to forget about screen shots, is there way to just make it unsavable like blob function etc?

Comment: No, as long as an image is displayed in browser, it may be saved to disk.